# Method is not returning a value in local machine for ruby

Tags: ruby

I am very new to Ruby. Started just few days back. I am learning from the website called [The Odin Project](http://theodinproject.com) and there they got this problem where I have to capitalize a word. I know how to capitalize but the method I am using doesn't seem to return the capitalized string.

I Tried the same code in [Repl.it](https://repl.it/JgzD). There it seems to return what I expected, but I can't get the same result in my local machine. I cant understand the problem. Can someone explain it to me..

Here's the code :

```
class Book
  attr_accessor :title
  def title= str
    str.capitalize!
  end #title

end #book

@book = Book.new
@book.title="inferno"
```

Comment: Use `capitalize`, not `capitalize!`. Also, your setter doesn't set anything. AND it overwrites the setter from `attr_accessor`.

Comment: Also, works for me, with this input: https://pastebin.com/syBNwcXm. Are you trying the same input on repl.it and your local machine?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I expect it _returns_ a capitalized string, but _does not set `@title` instance var_.

Comment: yes I am using the same input for both. and if i dont use `capitalize!` the string is not changing. and i didnt understand about the setter .

Comment: @mudasobwa: yep, except if the string is not capitalizable. "Returns nil if no changes are made."

Comment: @mudasobwa  it is changing the string to `capitalize` if i use a `puts` to print the string inside the method it  prints as expected. but i am not getting the expected return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For [`capitalize`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-capitalize) vs [`capitalize!`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-capitalize-21), the latter modifies the string in place, and returns `nil` if no substitution was made. The former, however, returns a new string with the replacements made. However, there's a weird thing using a setter like this in ruby, that I've yet to fully understand: ruby returns the value you passed in to the setter, not the last line executed as normal

```
class YourBook
  attr_accessor :title

  def title= str
    str.capitalize!
  end #title
end #book

new_title = "inferno"
@book = YourBook.new
puts @book.title = new_title # => Inferno # side note, this is because you modified the original string as seen down below
puts @book.title             # =>         # was never set
puts new_title               # => Inferno # the string in the original variable was mutated, which is why the setter returned the "correct" version

class MyBook
  attr_reader :title

  def title=(str)
    @title = str.capitalize
  end

  def set_title(val) # even with the odd return value from `title=`, I still recommend that instead of using `set_` methods
    @title = val.capitalize
  end
end

new_title = "inferno"
@book = MyBook.new
puts @book.title = new_title  # => inferno # side note, not sure why it does this, but ruby returned the string you entered, not the string you set
puts @book.title              # => Inferno # was set correctly
puts new_title                # => inferno # the original string was not mutated

new_title = "inferno two"
puts @book.set_title(new_title) # => Inferno two # as expected
puts @book.title                # => Inferno two # also as expected
puts new_title                     # => inferno two # again, didn't modify the original
```

Comment: Thank this solved the problem. But can you please give me some explanation on what i did wrong ??

Comment: @radioactive001 the only things I changed were 1) `attr_accessor` -> `attr_reader` because you define your own setter, so no need for the default one 2) you weren't setting the instance variable `@title` in your setter method (which, btw I still recommend over `set_title` even with this little oddity) and 3) `capitalize!` will return nil if no changes were made AND mutate the original string, which was making things appear to work with `capitalize!` and not with `capitalize`

Comment: and you'll notice in the [example specs](https://github.com/TheOdinProject/learn_ruby/blob/master/05_book_titles/book_titles_spec.rb) you gave, the author is checking `@book.title` after they call the setter, not checking the return value from the setter. This is to make sure they've remembered to actually set the instance variable and because of the weird return value thing shown in my code example

Answer (score 0):

This will depend on what exactly you want to achieve.  I'm trying to guess you want to capitalize the whole word there you have to use `upcase` method.

**EDIT**
I have rewritten your code to reflect your TDD needs.  I'm `initializing` the object the same way as your teaching TDD.  You need only `attr_accessor` which generates both setters and getters for `title`.

```
class Book
  attr_accessor :title

  def name_capitalize
    # only first letter capitalized
    title.capitalize
  end #title

end #book

@book = Book.new
@book.title="inferno" # stores the book title in the `@book.title`
# to print the book's name and first letter in capital
puts @book.name_capitalize # uses the stored `title` variable to return the capitalized name
```

Comment: I want to take a string and make the first character capital, so not `upcase` and the project is a Test Driven Development (here is the [Github link](https://github.com/TheOdinProject/learn_ruby/blob/master/05_book_titles/book_titles_spec.rb)  of the problem. so according to this is it necessary to use initialize method?

Comment: I see.  To reply to the first topic then use only `title.capitalize` instead.  To the second one I'll edit the answer to reflect the TDD link you showed me.

Answer (score 0):

Looking the code and trying to understand what you want, maybe I can clear your mind.

Your code is doing fine, the capitalize method is working properly. Like you said during the comments if you write puts inside the method it returns what you expect.

> @mudasobwa it is changing the string to capitalize if i use a puts to
>   print the string inside the method it prints as expected. but i am not
>   getting the expected return.

Now checking the call of this method.

```
@book.title="inferno"
```

Here we can see "inferno" passing an argument for title method. Then this method is returning the value, but nothing is getting it.

If you wanna check what's being returned just use puts(@book.title = "inferno").

```
class Book
  attr_accessor :title
  def title= str
    str.capitalize!
  end #title

end #book

@book = Book.new
puts(@book.title="inferno")
```